# Probability of Dependent Events

Tags: probability

Question: what is the probability of any member of a pool of 48 people getting one of 3 prizes if everyone stands an equal chance and no one can win more than one prize.

I know how to solve this calculating via not winning the prize and subtracting the outcome from 1, but I also tried solving it through adding the probabilities of a person winning the prizes directly. (1/48 + 1/47 + 1/46), however this gives the wrong answer. Please how can I calculate it through the probability of winning?

Thank you.

PS: the outcome should be 1/16

Answer (score 2):

So when doing these types of probability problems you should always think of the words OR and AND. 
When the question is what is the probability of A or B we add probabilities. When the question is what is the probability of A and B we multiply the probabilities.

In this case we want to know $P(\text{Winning one of 3 prizes})$

Think of the problem like this we want to now know the probability of not winning the first draw AND not winning the second draw AND not winning the third draw. Also, once someone wins they cannot be eligible to win again, so we need to reduce the population of possible winners each time by 1.

Remember the AND means multiplication.

Like you said it can sometimes be easier to figure out finding the probability of not winning ($P'$) and taking $1 - P' = P$

Therefore  $P'=\frac{47}{48}\times \frac{46}{47}\times \frac{45}{46}=.9375$

The probability of not winning 3 draws in a group of 48 people is $93.75\%$

So $P = 1 - .9375 = .0625 = 6.25\% = \frac{1}{16}$